# C# is it possible to override this method?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding

I am using external class A (from .dll file) and want to override one of the methods:

```
public void Method(); // notice that I cannot add 'virtual' keyword to enable override
```

Here is my code:

```
class B : A
{
  public new void Method();
}

A obj = new B();
obj.Method(); // executes A.Method() instead of B.Method()
```

Is it possible to override method Method from class A?

Note: I cannot change to B obj = new B(); (must stay A type)

Comment: Why is obj of class A?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič you should create an answer

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič Actually I am operating on A obj (I cannot change that) I can only create instance (obj = new B())

Comment: If the method is not virtual, you have no access to class A *and* you are not the one calling `obj.Method()`, then no, it is impossible to do what you want.

Comment: OP I have to say, there's a lot you apparently can't change about this code. I'm genuinely intrigued to find out what the context of it all is. Your hands are tied if you have no permission to emend certain bits of it.

Comment: @user1334190 : you are trying to break the desing principles.. however if the scenario exists "Marko Juvančič's" solution works really well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible

However there's a workaround.

```
A obj = new B();

if (obj is B) {
 (obj as B).Method(); 
} else {
  obj.Method();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that it is not me who call method Method() (it is called somewhere where it I have no access). Although, your approach can be really helpfull. Thanks!

Comment: So you have a class which you cannot change and it's being call from somewhere else where you cannot access. Complicated.
What if that caller calls your code and you route it correctly?

Comment: Why the downvote? @MarkoJuvančič answered the question with "not possible" then proposed a workaround. It's helpful for everyone involved if downvoters explain their decision.

Comment: @DeeMac I downvoted it because of the "work around". It's a horrible, brittle, hack. A much better solution would be to eg use the decorator pattern and to wrap A in another class.

Comment: @DavidArno You can write a better answer. Afterall, SO is about making the Internet a better place.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's isn't possible to override the method.

Although you can specify a new version in `B`:

```
public new void Method();
```

This isn't overriding the method, as any calls through the base class, `A` will dispatch to the implementation in `A` as there is no virtual slot for the method. The compiler decides what to call be looking at the static type of `obj` at compile time. It sees that `obj` is an `A` and that `Method` is not virtual, so calls the `A` implementation.

Comment: As you can see I did it and it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @user1334190 - The only solution to your problem is, if possible, to modify `A` to that `Method` is declared `virtual`. Nothing else will give you the right consistent behaviour for overriding.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to override a method that is not declared virtual in the base class.

As the other answers mention, you can hide such methods, by declaring a new method with the same name. But this isn't going to achieve the results you want: calls to `Method` through an object of compile-time type `A` will always run the `A` method, and calls via an object of compile-time type `B` will always run the `B` method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are **hiding** the `Method` in your A class by re-declaring it in the class B. But you are making a mistake in this part:

```
A obj = new B();
```

So you have to change to the below form, if you'd like to access `Method` from B class

```
B obj = new B();
```

Comment: As I was trying to explain in comment above, unfortunately I cannot change it

Comment: If the method is virtual then declaring A obj=new B(), obj.Method() would call the B.Method(). This is what virtual is all about.

Comment: @user1334190: You don'y have to change anything in the base class, just consider changing the way you created the object as I explained.

Comment: @Plexus In my code I have access to obj that is A-type. So I can assign creating new object by obj = new A() (or B()) but I cannot change the type of obj